# How to rename uploaded file with fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an endpoint that allows users to upload files.  I would like to rename the file to a random and unique file name but can't work out how to change the filename.  My current code is as follows which is saving the file to files/filename

```
@router.post('/qualifications/file')
async def create_file(files: UploadFile = File(...)):
   file_location = f"files/{files.filename}"
   with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
      file_object.write(files.file.read())
      return {"info": f"file '{files.filename}' saved at '{file_location}'"}
```

Comment: You can [use the `secrets` module to generate a random identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe), then use that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you generate a custom file location instead of using `files.filename`? You may have to work out what the `files.filename` extension was and pass that into the new file_name you are creating.

```py
@router.post('/qualifications/file')
async def create_file(files: UploadFile = File(...)):\

   file_name = "some_random_name.txt"

   file_location = f"files/{file_name}"

   with open(file_location, "wb+") as file_object:
      file_object.write(files.file.read())
      return {"info": f"file '{file_name}' saved at '{file_location}'"}
```

Comment: that was easier than I was trying to make it, thank you.  For anybody else interested, I'm getting the filename extension with `extension = files.filename.split(".")[1]`

Comment: glad this helped!